# How to remove image tag when empty src or without src

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$content = '<img src=""><img alt="test" width="400px"><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>';
$content = preg_replace('!(<a\s[^>]+>)?<img([^>]+)src=""([^>]*)>(</a>)?!i' , '' , $content );
echo $content;
```

But only able to remove `src=""`, can't remove without src

```
<img alt="test" width="400px"><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the regex,  `<img(?![^>]*(src="[^"]+"))[^>]*>` .

The negative lookahead `(?![^>]*(src="[^"]+")` will not capture the img tag with `src="..."`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bROZIc/2)